# Universal Distribution groups in WIN NT

Tags: windows, domain-controller, groups

we have a domain with "**Mixed domain functional level**".
there are **3 DCs** in this domain with (**Win2003, Win2000 & WinNT**) OSs.
here we can create a "Universal Distribution group" on the DC with Win2000 or Win2003.
it is remarkable that there wont be any inconsistency in this domain whereas the Universal scope & distribution type are not defined in WinNT !!

Any body knows how WinNT is compatible with a Universal Distribution group on above case scenario??

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my advice is "Get rid of the NT DC." Out of morbid curiosity, why do you still have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this MS page about what features are available at a given [Domain and forest functionality levels.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738670%28WS.10%29.aspx)

> **Windows 2000 mixed - Universal Groups** - Enabled for distribution groups.  Disabled for security groups.

So do answer your question, I don't believe there is any consistency issue, since Windows NT doesn't support distribution groups.  I believe they are never sent to NT4 DC.

Comment: Thanx for the link,
but if you check the link, its written there that distribution groups are supported by a domain with "Mixed dfl".
Mixed dfl: (WinNT, Win2000, Win2003)
whereas distribution groups are not defined in WinNT!

and based on my experience, universal distribution groups are supported as well,
just I cant figure out the reason beyond that..

Comment: I am confused about what you are saying in your comment.  Windows NT doesn't support universal groups, because it doesn't support universal groups.  Windows NT doesn't support distribution groups.  You can have both in a mixed domain, but the NT4 DC, will not understand or care about the things it doesn't support.  In any case, it is well past the time to retire that NT4 DC.